# Static Finalizer

Tags: c#, .net, static, destructor, finalizer

What is the right way to perform some static finallization?

There is no static destructor. The `AppDomain.DomainUnload` event is not raised in the default domain. The `AppDomain.ProcessExit` event shares the total time of the three seconds (default settings) between all event handlers, so it's not really usable.

Comment: First, in C#, we need to get out of the habit of using finalizer and destructor interchangably.  One is deterministic, the other is not.  It's interesting to note that the C# spec gets the terms backward from the CLR and other .NET language specs.  It's also interesting to note that the C# language committee's notes explicitly say there are no foreseen reasons why C# can't have static finalizers.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1875149/56793

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Basically, you can't. Design your way around it to the fullest extent possible.

Don't forget that a program can *always* terminate abruptly anyway - someone pulling out the power being the obvious example. So anything you do has to be "best effort" - in which case I'd certainly *hope* that `AppDomain.ProcessExit` would be good enough.

What do you need to do, in your particular case?

Comment: How does this answer relate to the answer by Michael (since it seems it is possible to have static finalizers)? (Either way I agree that finalizers are unreliable.)

Comment: @mafutrct: Michael's answer isn't really a static finalizer. It's a static field with a reference to an instance which has a finalizer. It's not the same thing, even though it could have similar effects. I wouldn't use it personally.

Comment: The true value of a static finalizer--from the perspective of a Delphi developer where such things are supported at the language level--isn't some nonsensical "guarantee that this will run," (as you point out, someone could always pull the plug,) but rather a guarantee that *it will run when the class goes out of scope.* If the assembly containing the class was loaded dynamically as a plugin, and gets unloaded before program termination, this can be a pretty significant distinction, and having a cleanup routine that runs at process exit is no good. How do you handle that scenario "correctly"?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Well you'd normally have a plugin within its own AppDomain, in which case you could subscribe to the `AppDomain.DomainUnload` event. (There's no such concept as a class going "out of scope" as a class isn't in a scope to start with.)

Answer (score 51):

> Herfried Wagner has written an [excellent article](http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/articles/sharedfinalizer/) explaining how to implement this – alas, in German (and VB). Still, the code should be understandable.

I've tried it:

```
static readonly Finalizer finalizer = new Finalizer();

sealed class Finalizer {
  ~Finalizer() {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("one");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("two");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("three");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("four");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("five");
  }
}
```

It seems to work exactly the same way as the `AppDomain.ProcessExit` event does: the finalizer gets ca. three seconds...

Comment: This is the best answer as you can debug your "finaliser" in this way, whereas the AppDomain.ProcessExit delegate doesn't allow you to debug it (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 8):

Two solutions that jump to mind:

- Don't use a static class.  If you use a non-static class and instantiate it, you don't have to worry about cleanup as much.
- If that's not an option, I'd argue that this is a good situation to use a singleton.  This will instantiate a copy of your object and have the finalizer called on exit, but still allow you to treat it like a static class for the most part.  After all, your class is static already and therefore shares most of the common reasons not to use a singleton.

Answer (score 6):

I would question what you are loading in your static methods that need to be released. I certainly wouldn't recommend doing these things in a static method.

That said, your static method could instanciate an object that has a finalise method.

Answer (score 2):

To port Michael Damatov's answer (C#) which is based on Herfried K. Wagner. (VB.NET) here is the C++/CLI version:

```
ref class MyClass
{
        ref class StaticFinalizer sealed
        {
            !StaticFinalizer();
        };
        static initonly StaticFinalizer^ stDestr = gcnew StaticFinalizer();
}

MyClass::StaticFinalizer::!StaticFinalizer()
{
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("In StaticFinalizer!");
}
```

P.S. Just like the AppDomain.ProcessExit method, this one may not be called if the process is terminated abnormally (from Task Manager for example). 
Another word of caution is that if MyClass is generic (templated), the assumption that its static constructor and static destructor will be called no more than once per application execution is no longer be valid.