# How to enforce the use of a method's return value in C#?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, attributes, lazy-loading, return-value

I have a piece of software written with fluent syntax. The method chain has a definitive "ending", before which nothing useful is actually done in the code (think NBuilder, or Linq-to-SQL's query generation not actually hitting the database until we iterate over our objects with, say, ToList()).

The problem I am having is there is confusion among other developers about proper usage of the code. They are neglecting to call the "ending" method (thus never actually "doing anything")!

I am interested in **enforcing the usage of the return value** of some of my methods so that we can never "end the chain" without calling that "Finalize()" or "Save()" method that actually does the work.

Consider the following code:

```
//The "factory" class the user will be dealing with
public class FluentClass
{
    //The entry point for this software
    public IntermediateClass<T> Init<T>()
    {
        return new IntermediateClass<T>();
    }
}

//The class that actually does the work
public class IntermediateClass<T>
{
    private List<T> _values;

    //The user cannot call this constructor
    internal IntermediateClass<T>()
    {
        _values = new List<T>();
    }

    //Once generated, they can call "setup" methods such as this
    public IntermediateClass<T> With(T value)
    {
        var instance = new IntermediateClass<T>() { _values = _values };
        instance._values.Add(value);
        return instance;
    }

    //Picture "lazy loading" - you have to call this method to
    //actually do anything worthwhile
    public void Save()
    {
        var itemCount = _values.Count();
        . . . //save to database, write a log, do some real work
    }
}
```

As you can see, proper usage of this code would be something like:

```
new FluentClass().Init<int>().With(-1).With(300).With(42).Save();
```

The problem is that people are using it this way (thinking it achieves the same as the above):

```
new FluentClass().Init<int>().With(-1).With(300).With(42);
```

So pervasive is this problem that, with entirely good intentions, another developer once actually changed the name of the "Init" method to indicate that THAT method was doing the "real work" of the software.

Logic errors like these are very difficult to spot, and, of course, it compiles, because it is perfectly acceptable to call a method with a return value and just "pretend" it returns void. Visual Studio doesn't care if you do this; your software will still compile and run (although in some cases I believe it throws a warning). This is a great feature to have, of course. Imagine a simple "InsertToDatabase" method that returns the ID of the new row as an integer - it is easy to see that there are some cases where we need that ID, and some cases where we could do without it.

In the case of this piece of software, there is definitively never any reason to eschew that "Save" function at the end of the method chain. It is a very specialized utility, and the only gain comes from the final step.

I want somebody's software to **fail at the compiler level** if they call "With()" and not "Save()".

It seems like an impossible task by traditional means - but that's why I come to you guys. Is there an Attribute I can use to prevent a method from being "cast to void" or some such?

**Note:** The alternate way of achieving this goal that has already been suggested to me is writing a suite of unit tests to enforce this rule, and using something like http://www.testdriven.net to bind them to the compiler. This is an acceptable solution, but I am hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Total shot in the dark, I have no knowledge that this is possible, but maybe .NET Code Contracts? I think they're built into .NET 4.0

Comment: Code Contracts does not have an attribute or assertion which requires checking the return value.

Comment: I would consider this API not usable if these kinds of issues arise. Why did you use a fluent interface pattern here?

Comment: The fluent interface was by the request of the client. Solutions like Tejs' and Vercas' are technically foolproof but involve syntax changes; ultimately I could play with these and then see if the client can deal with the API change, but since the software is already in use, it would be nice to be able to apply a hotfix without changing any of the public method signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After great deliberation and trial and error, it turns out that throwing an exception from the Finalize() method was not going to work for me. Apparently, you simply can't do that; the exception gets eaten up, because garbage collection operates non-deterministically. I was unable to get the software to call Dispose() automatically from the destructor either. Jack V.'s comment explains this well; here was the link he posted, for redundancy/emphasis:

[The difference between a destructor and a finalizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872700/the-difference-between-a-destructor-and-a-finalizer)

Changing the syntax to use a callback was a clever way to make the behavior foolproof, but the agreed-upon syntax was fixed, and I had to work with it. Our company is all about fluent method chains. I was also a fan of the "out parameter" solution to be honest, but again, the bottom line is the method signatures simply could not change.

Helpful information about my particular problem includes the fact that my software is ***only ever*** to be run as part of a suite of unit tests - so efficiency is not a problem.

What I ended up doing was use *Mono.Cecil* to Reflect upon the Calling Assembly (the code calling into my software). Note that *System.Reflection* was insufficient for my purposes, because it cannot pinpoint method references, but I still needed(?) to use it to get the "calling assembly" itself (Mono.Cecil remains underdocumented, so it's possible I just need to get more familiar with it in order to do away with System.Reflection altogether; that remains to be seen....)

I placed the *Mono.Cecil* code in the **Init()** method, and the structure now looks something like:

```
public IntermediateClass<T> Init<T>()
{
    ValidateUsage(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
    return new IntermediateClass<T>();
}

void ValidateUsage(Assembly assembly)
{
    // 1) Use Mono.Cecil to inspect the codebase inside the assembly
    var assemblyLocation = assembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "");
    var monoCecilAssembly = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(assemblyLocation);

    // 2) Retrieve the list of Instructions in the calling method
    var methods = monoCecilAssembly.Modules...Types...Methods...Instructions
    // (It's a little more complicated than that...
    //  if anybody would like more specific information on how I got this,
    //  let me know... I just didn't want to clutter up this post)

    // 3) Those instructions refer to OpCodes and Operands....
    //    Defining "invalid method" as a method that calls "Init" but not "Save"
    var methodCallingInit = method.Body.Instructions.Any
        (instruction => instruction.OpCode.Name.Equals("callvirt")
                     && instruction.Operand is IMethodReference
                     && instruction.Operand.ToString.Equals(INITMETHODSIGNATURE);

    var methodNotCallingSave = !method.Body.Instructions.Any
        (instruction => instruction.OpCode.Name.Equals("callvirt")
                     && instruction.Operand is IMethodReference
                     && instruction.Operand.ToString.Equals(SAVEMETHODSIGNATURE);

    var methodInvalid = methodCallingInit && methodNotCallingSave;

    // Note: this is partially pseudocode;
    // It doesn't 100% faithfully represent either Mono.Cecil's syntax or my own
    // There are actually a lot of annoying casts involved, omitted for sanity

    // 4) Obviously, if the method is invalid, throw
    if (methodInvalid)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Bad developer! BAD! {0}", method.Name));
    }
}
```

Trust me, the actual code is even uglier looking than my pseudocode.... :-)

But Mono.Cecil just might be my new favorite toy.

I now have a method that refuses to be run its main body unless the calling code "promises" to also call a second method afterwards. It's like a strange kind of code contract. I'm actually thinking about making this generic and reusable. Would any of you have a use for such a thing? Say, if it were an attribute?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of a way to enforce this at a compiler level.  It's often requested for objects which implement `IDisposable` as well, but isn't really enforceable.

One potential option which can help, however, is to set up your class, *in DEBUG only*, to have a finalizer that logs/throws/etc. if `Save()` was never called.  This can help you discover these runtime problems while debugging instead of relying on searching the code, etc.

However, make sure that, in release mode, this is not used, as it will incur a performance overhead since the addition of an unnecessary finalizer is very bad on GC performance.

Comment: +1, for the clever finalizer trick in Debug, used it before to remind myself of critical managed-native failures in code.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like it. Especially because, and here's the kicker that I didn't mention in the original post, my software **itself** is made only for tests; I don't even have to specify "debug only" because the code already has no place in the main class library. I'll try this out soon to see if I can get it to work, but after deliberating on it for a while, I do suspect you've nailed it (for my purposes at least). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could require specific methods to use a callback like so:

```
new FluentClass().Init<int>(x =>
{
    x.Save(y =>
    {
         y.With(-1),
         y.With(300)
    });
});
```

The with method returns some specific object, and the only way to get that object is by calling x.Save(), which itself has a callback that lets you set up your indeterminate number of with statements. So the init takes something like this:

```
public T Init<T>(Func<MyInitInputType, MySaveResultType> initSetup)
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you made it so `Init` and `With` don't return objects of type `FluentClass`?  Have them return, e.g., `UninitializedFluentClass` which wraps a `FluentClass` object.  Then calling `.Save(0` on the `UnitializedFluentClass` object calls it on the wrapped `FluentClass` object and returns it.  If they don't call `Save` they don't get a `FluentClass` object.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of <s>three</s> a few solutions, not ideal.

1. AIUI what you want is a function which is called when the temporary variable goes out of scope (as in, when it becomes available for garbage collection, but will probably not be garbage collected for some time yet). (See: [The difference between a destructor and a finalizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872700/the-difference-between-a-destructor-and-a-finalizer)) This hypothetical function would say "if you've constructed a query in this object but not called save, produce an error". C++/CLI calls this RAII, and in C++/CLI there is a concept of a "destructor" when the object isn't used any more, and a "finaliser" which is called when it's finally garbage collected. Very confusingly, C# has only a so-called destructor, but this is *only* called by the garbage collector (it would be valid for the framework to call it earlier, as if it were partially cleaning the object immediately, but AFAIK it doesn't do anything like that). So what you would like is a C++/CLI destructor. Unfortunately, AIUI this maps onto the concept of IDisposable, which exposes a dispose() method which can be called when a C++/CLI destructor would be called, or when the C# destructor is called -- but AIUI you still have to call "dispose" manually, which defeats the point?
2. Refactor the interface slightly to convey the concept more accurately. Call the init function something like "prepareQuery" or "AAA" or "initRememberToCallSaveOrThisWontDoAnything". (The last is an exaggeration, but it might be necessary to make the point).
3. This is more of a social problem than a technical problem. The interface should make it easy to do the right thing, but programmers do have to know how to use code! Get all the programmers together. Explain simply once-and-for-all this simple fact. If necessary have them all sign a piece of paper saying they understand, and if they wilfully continue to write code which doesn't do anythign they're worse than useless to the company and will be fired.
4. Fiddle with the way the operators are chained, eg. have each of the intermediateClass functions assemble an aggregate intermediateclass object containing all of the parameters (you mostly do it this was already (?)) but require an init-like function of the original class to take that as an argument, rather than have them chained after it, and then you can have save and the other functions return two different class types (with essentially the same contents), and have init only accept a class of the correct type.

The fact that it's *still* a problem suggests that either your coworkers need a helpful reminder, or they're rather sub-par, or the interface wasn't very clear (perhaps its perfectly good, but the author didn't realise it wouldn't be clear if you only used it in passing rather than getting to know it), or you yourself have misunderstood the situation. A technical solution would be good, but you should probably think about why the problem occurred and how to communicate more clearly, probably asking someone senior's input.

Answer (score 0):

In Debug mode beside implementing IDisposable you can setup a timer that will throw a exception after 1 second if the resultmethod has not been called.

Comment: One second could be dangerously short if the system is overloaded. You could instead throw an exception in the finalizer. Both techniques add overhead, but the timer is probably more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `out` parameter! All the `out`s must be used.

Edit: I am not sure of it will help, tho...
It would break the fluent syntax.